# Angular JS within visualforce

Tags: visualforce, angularjs, angular

Hi This is a generic question

I was looking through a piece of code and came across the following within a visualforce page. Can anyone give me any ideas as to what it means exactly. It looks like angular js about which I have no idea what so ever . So any tutorial with some starting point will be appreciated.

```
<html lang="en-US" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"  ng-app="ngApp" id="ng-app" ng-controller="masterCtrl">
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is typical Angular code. Look for `.js` files included in the page and inside those you will find JavaScript used by the page.

There is a lot more to Angular than those declarations: if you really want to understand I suggest you work your way through this [AngularJS Fundamentals](https://egghead.io/courses/angularjs-app-from-scratch-getting-started) material from https://egghead.io. Their format is short and very much to the point videos: I've found them really helpful.